# Как сделать так, чтобы маршрутизация не обращала внимания на точку?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, маршрутизация

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я типо обращаюсь к какому-то фалу в какой-то папке, прописал сначала такой маршрут:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{path}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

И когда писал сам запрос, с path всё было хорошо, но как только добавил точку в середину, получилась ошибка. Маршрутизация, похоже, воспринимает точку как разделитель. Ни это

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{path}/{extension}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Ни это:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{path}.{extension}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Не помогло. Скорее всего он пытается реально найти такой файл, но как сделать так, чтобы работало как мне нужно?

Comment: Проблема с точкой - старая и давно известная, решений несколько, например - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/3768545

Answer (score -1):

Если кто-то столкнётся с тем же, у меня не заработало то, что скинули в коментах, потому что свойство system.web в Web.config просто не может иметь детей handlers, как писала ошибка в браузере. Может быть это из-за версии iis 10, но это факт. Могу быть дети httpHandlers, но это свойство не может иметь детей add)))
  Поэтому моё решение: в методе RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes файла RouteConfig.cs (который в App_Start) в самом начале прописать

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

и в конфигарационном файле iis в строке

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
```

в атрибуте preCondition сделать строку пустой.
Но учтите, что все запросы на iis перенаправляются на фреймвёрк и вам самим нужно обрабатывать эти маршруты, так, например я не смог в img прописать ресурс напрямую на сервер, значит скорее всего и с css и с js будет тоже самое, но это уже не точно, но скорее всего)